# Powershell: Error wieth Set-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm attempting to write a script that checks an AD OU for any accounts that are enabled, or set to not have a password required, or password never to expire, or not set to be hidden from the address list.  Then, the script will disable any of those for security purposes.  Here's the script so far:

```
Function Update-ADUser 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$user
    )
BEGIN{}
PROCESS{
    Set-ADUser -instance $user -Server dc01 
    }
END{}
}

$lostUsers = Get-ADUser -filter {PasswordNotRequired -eq $true -or PasswordNeverExpires -eq $true -or Enabled -eq $true -or msExchHideFromAddressLists -eq $false } -SearchBase "OU=Lost Users,OU=DEPT,DC=School,DC=edu" -Server dc01  -properties enabled, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordNotRequired, msExchHideFromAddressLists
foreach ($user in $lostUsers)
    {
        if ($user.PasswordNotRequired -eq $true)
        {
            $user.PasswordNotRequired = $false
        }

        if ($user.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $true)
        {
            $user.PasswordNeverExpires = $false
        }
        if ($user.msExchHideFromAddressLists -ne $true  )
        {
            $user.msExchHideFromAddressLists = $true
        }
        if ($user.Enabled -eq $true)
        {
            $user.Enabled = $false
        }
        Update-ADUser -user $user
    }
```

Most of the script runs fine.  `$lostUsers` creates an array that uses `Get-ADUser` to search for only records that have one of the attributes required.  Then my `foreach/if` statements set each attribute to what is should be for each record.

My problem occurs when I call the `Update-ADUser` function.  I keep getting an error, `Set-ADUser : The instance parameter object must be of type: 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser'.`

I tried removing the [string] from `[string]$user` in the function but that gives me another error, `Set-ADUser : The server is unwilling to process the request.`  I'm using an domain admin account to run the script, so I know that's not causing this error.

I could use `Set-ADUser` in each `if` statement, instead of calling the `Update-ADUser` function, but that doesn't seem efficient as the script is then making up to four changes per record instead of just one with the function.  I also thought about just using one statement to change all four attributes for all the found records, but that seems inefficient as well since some attributes were already correctly set and would thus just be written over again.

I can't figure out why the `Set-ADUser` command isn't working. I basically copied the syntax from the `Set-ADUser` help.  Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: Update: Upon further research, I found out that null attributes can cause the "unwilling to process the request error."  However, checking a test $user and I'm not seeing any nulls but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what I'm missing here but wouldn't replacing the line (at the very end of your foreach)

```
Update-ADUser -user $user
```

with...

```
Set-ADUser -instance $user -Server dc01
```

...do exactly what you want?

Comment: Yes, I could write it that way, but no, it still doesn't work; I get the same error.

Comment: You might have to use Disable-ADAccount instead of $user.Enabled = $false to get it done. Different sources on the web seem to suggest other attributes are involved in disabling an account. Unfortunatly I have no way of testing this at the moment.

Comment: Update:  I changed the last line to Set-ADUser -instance $user -Server dc01 as suggested.  I also changed the if statements to check if an attribute was "not equal" instead of "equal" to some value.  Seems like a small change but it made a huge difference because while some attributes might not be equal to "true" that doesn't mean they are set to "false."  They could be null and that was a problem.  Seems Set-ADUser doesn't like setting things to null.  So, my script then made sure any of the values I was changing actually had a value (either $true or $false but no null values).

Comment: Update part 2:  (cont. from previous update...)  So, my script then worked!

Comment: Update part 2:  (cont. from previous update...)  So, my script then worked!  Except now it doesn't again.  I added some more code the the script--just to add events to Event Logs and email me if any changes were made--and put it up on our script server to run daily.  After finally getting the bugs worked out to write to the event log and send email, I tested the script and now I'm getting the "server is unwilling to process the request " errors again.  UGH! Thanks MS for making such detailed error messages {sarcasm font}.  So, I'm not sure what the issue is now.